# Circular UILabel Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel with width 20 and height 80. I wanna make it circular.
Following is the code I used:-

```
self.trackBackgroundLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.trackBackgroundLabel.layer.cornerRadius = self.trackBackgroundLabel.frame.size.height/2;
```

but it didnt come out as proper circle. Please help.

[image]

Comment: The corner radius to make circle works only if the view is a square.

Comment: Use width/2 instead of height/2. Square would be best though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a circle as the same radius on all sides. it is basically a 'round square' -- 80x20 isnt a proper square ;) so your 'circle' is an 'oval' to fill the rectangle given.

square the UILabel